# rails application display blank html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger

- Ruby 1.92
- Rails 3.1.1
- Nginx 1.1.6
- Passenger 3.0.7

My rails application works fine on my laptop, but it does not work on amazon server. I open it in chrome, browser display nothing, HTTP header like below:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 302
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger (mod_rails/mod_rack) 3.0.7
```

If I run `rails server`, it does work, I can get correct html. Nginx cannot generate correct `content-length`?

nginx config

```
server {
        listen 8000;
        server_name xxxx;
        root /xxx/xxx/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env development;


      location = /favicon.ico {
        expires    max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
      } 


      location ~* \.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|css|js|swf|ico)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
        access_log off;
        expires max;
       add_header Cache-Control public;
      }

}
```

http raw message is below

total 3496 bytes return, content-length is wrong,so browser do read rest html

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 200
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger (mod_rails/mod_rack) 3.0.7
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
ETag: "12aa68a45bf774886311f827d2149cbe"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
X-Runtime: 0.499998
Server: nginx/1.1.6 + Phusion Passenger 3.0.7 (mod_rails/mod_rack)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>xxxx</title>
......
```

Comment: what does your production.log say?

Comment: no error in log file
i use fiddle to capture http message, server does retun some html, but hhtp header:content-length is 0, so browser can not display html .

Answer (score 0):

A HTTP status of 302 is usually a redirect. Are there any other headers or body content? I'd expect a location header telling the browser where to redirect to.

Comment: http status is 200
actually, server return whole html just with wrong content-length=0

http header :
<pre>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 200
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger (mod_rails/mod_rack) 3.0.7
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
ETag: "12aa68a45bf774886311f827d2149cbe"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Server: nginx/1.1.6 + Phusion Passenger 3.0.7 (mod_rails/mod_rack)
</pre>